# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo problems

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I want to open another activity when a button is clicked. I can't see where the problem are.. I hope someone here could tell me whats wrong.

onClick from activity one:

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bBerakna:

        if (isEditTextEmpty(anslag_mm) | isEditTextEmpty(bladVikten)
                | isEditTextEmpty(jamnViktsLage)
                | isEditTextEmpty(rotorSpann) | isEditTextEmpty(varv_Minut)) {

            Toast t = Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Du måste fylla i alla parametrarna!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.show();
            break;
        } else {
            Intent resultat = new Intent(Input.this,
                    ExpandableListViewAppActivity.class);
            resultat.putExtra("ROTOR", rotorSp);
            resultat.putExtra("RPM", rpm);
            resultat.putExtra("JVIKT", jämVikL);
            resultat.putExtra("BVIKT", bladVikt);
            resultat.putExtra("ANSLAG", anslFäLä);              
            startActivity(resultat);
        }
    };
```

And this is onCreate of activity two that should be opened:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent getIntent = getIntent();
        rotorSp = (double) getIntent.getDoubleExtra("ROTOR", 0);
        rpm = (double) getIntent.getDoubleExtra("RPM", 0);
        jämVikL = (double) getIntent.getDoubleExtra("JVIKT", 0);
        bladVikt = (double) getIntent.getDoubleExtra("BVIKT", 0);
        anslFäLä = (double) getIntent.getDoubleExtra("ANSLAG", 0);

    berakna();

    // Döljer tangentbordet
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

}
```

this is from the LogCat:

```
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rotorbladen.tobias/com.rotorbladen.tobias.ExpandableListViewAppActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at com.rotorbladen.tobias.ExpandableListViewAppActivity.onCreate(ExpandableListViewAppActivity.java:92)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
   01-20 19:09:09.068: E/AndroidRuntime(722):   ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is line `92` of `ExpandableListViewAppActivity`? Also, `getDoubleExtra()` returns a primitive double. The cast isn't needed.

Comment: Post the `berakna();` method

Comment: this is line 92 of ExpandableListViewAppActivity:
 getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),

as seen in the activity two source above.

berakna are just calculations that i know works and i can see the results in the debugger.

Comment: I solved my problem thanks to A--C i removed the inputmethodmanagern.